# dial tcp remote_ip:6379: connect: connection timed out

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I'm using redigo for both regular commands as well as subscribing. Every few days I get this error which causes a panic.

```
dial tcp IP:6379: connect: connection timed out
```

I'm guessing there is a some lag or minor disturbance with the network which is causing the connection to time out.

How can I avoid this? I'm OK with the program waiting a few seconds until the problem is resolves, rather than panicking.

How can I avoid this? Should I define Timeouts for Dial? Such as

- `DialReadTimeout`
- `DialWriteTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DialConnectTimeout](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#DialConnectTimeout) to specify a timeout for dialing a network connection or [DialNetDial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#DialNetDial) for complete control over dialing a network connection.

The application supplied NetDial function can set timeouts, throttle connect attempts on failure, and more.

Panics related to a dial failure are probably due to a lack of error checking in the application.

DialWriteTimeout and DialReadTimeout are dial options for specifying the timeout when writing a command to the network connection and reading a reply from the network connection respectively. These options have no bearing on timeouts during connect.

Comment: Do you know of a good way to test DialConnectTimeout? Is there a default timeout Redigo will set if DialConnectTimeout is not specified?

Comment: Redigo passes the application specified timeout to the network dialer.  Redigo does not add any timeouts of its own. Testing that DialConnectTimeout sets [network dial timeout](https://godoc.org/net#Dialer.Timeout) will take some effort, but [the code](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo/blob/bb5990dc771ab24e169aaea90ee3b9ad50cffce9/redis/conn.go#L102-L108) is simple enough that I think you can assume that it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will further investigate how to trigger some sort of network timeout myself. I'll add my findings here if I do find something.